# Handle thorn delimiter in pig

Tags: hadoop, unicode, apache-pig

My Source is a log file having "þ" as  delimiter.I am trying to read this file in Pig.Please look at the options I tried.

Option 1 :

Using PigStorage("þ") - This does'nt work out as it cant handle unicode characters.

Option 2 :

I tried reading the lines as string and tried to split the line with "þ".This also does'nt work out as the STRSPLIT left out the last field as it has "\n" in the end.

I can see multiple questions in web, but unable to find a solution.
Kindly direct me with this.

Thorn Details : 
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe/index.htm

Comment: I would preprocess the file and replace unicode character with something that can be handled by PIG easily and then pass the file to PIG.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Gaurav.So It means we cant do in PIG for sure ? I roamed around different approach.Nothing worked.

Comment: I may not be able to tell you if it CAN NOT be done, but yes for the ways I think it looks difficult if not impossible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the solution are you expecting?

```
input.txt:  
helloþworldþhelloþworld  
helloþworldþhelloþworld  
helloþworldþhelloþworld  
helloþworldþhelloþworld  
helloþworldþhelloþworld  

PigScript:
A = LOAD 'input.txt' as line;  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(.*)þ(.*)þ(.*)þ(.*)'));  
dump B;  

Output:  
(hello,world,hello,world)  
(hello,world,hello,world)  
(hello,world,hello,world)  
(hello,world,hello,world)  
(hello,world,hello,world)
```

Added 2nd option with different datatypes:

```
input.txt  
helloþ1234þ1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00þworld  
helloþ4567þ1990-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00þworld  
helloþ8901þ2001-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00þworld  
helloþ9876þ2014-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00þworld  

PigScript:  
A = LOAD 'input.txt' as line;  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(.*)þ(.*)þ(.*)þ(.*)')) as (f1:chararray,f2:long,f3:datetime,f4:chararray);  
DUMP B;  
DESCRIBE B;

Output:
(hello,1234,1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00,world)  
(hello,4567,1990-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00,world)  
(hello,8901,2001-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00,world)  
(hello,9876,2014-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00,world)  

B: {f1: chararray,f2: long,f3: datetime,f4: chararray}
```

Another thorn symbol A¾:

```
input.txt  
1077A¾04-01-2014Ã¾04-30-2014Ã¾0Ã¾0.0Ã¾0  
1077A¾04-01-2014Ã¾04-30-2014Ã¾0Ã¾0.0Ã¾0  
1077A¾04-01-2014Ã¾04-30-2014Ã¾0Ã¾0.0Ã¾0  

PigScript:  
A = LOAD 'jinput.txt' as line;  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(.*)A¾(.*)Ã¾(.*)Ã¾(.*)Ã¾(.*)Ã¾(.*)')) as (f1:long,f2:datetime,f3:datetime,f4:int,f5:double,f6:int);  
DUMP B;  
describe B;  

Output:  
(1077,04-01-2014,04-30-2014,0,0.0,0)  
(1077,04-01-2014,04-30-2014,0,0.0,0)  
(1077,04-01-2014,04-30-2014,0,0.0,0) 
B: {f1: long,f2: datetime,f3: datetime,f4: int,f5: double,f6: int}
```

}

Comment: Siva,I can see this method works for chararray but not for long or date field values. Any Suggestions? Working with delimiter is possible in PIG ?

Comment: Can you try to change the second line like this   B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(.*)þ(.*)þ(.*)þ(.*)')) as (f1:chararray,f2:long,f3:datetime,f4:chararray); Now f1 and f4 are chararray, f2 is long and f3 is datetime. Now by using this f1-f4 variable you can process whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for repsponse, Siva. your scenario and answers are right.But if you see my data input file will be: `1077A¾04-01-2014Ã¾04-30-2014Ã¾0Ã¾0.0Ã¾0 `. Here **Ã¾** is delimiter (thorn). This is why I am not segregate the fields properly.Any comments ?

Comment: For this thorn A¾ symbol also it will work. check the answer area.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (replace the unicode code point with the one that's working for you, this is for capital thorn):

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING 
B = FOREACH A GENERATE STRSPLIT(f1, '\\u00DE', -1);
```

I don't see why the last field should be left out.

Somehow, this does not work:

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage('\00DE');
```